# How to update an image with a new image after restarting the animation cycle Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, jquery-animate, css-animations

I recently created my first Javascript program. I'm extremely new to this (about 3 days) and would really love some help as I am completely stumped on what to do next. As of right now I intend to have the program function as follows:

purpose: A streamlabs widget acting as a bit/donation goal

A bunny slowly animating towards a finish at the other end of the screen, a few inches per donation. Upon reaching the finish line, it starts from the beginning again, levels up into a different color or image, repeats, keeps leveling up and so on.

I have finished all animations, movement per donation, and resetting back into the original bunny and repeat, but I am having trouble with changing the image or color from block (which is the bunny) to gold (a golden bunny) and changing for every level up(after hitting the end of the screen and restarting).

I have an event listener already set up and working, for this sake I included a run button to interact with moving the bunny.

*bonus*
I would later down the line like to have the bunny have dialog after each animation. Somewhere along the lines of "20% through!", or "almost there!"

Could I get any help with some Javascript experts? How would I go about doing this? Thank you

```js
$("#go").click(function() {
  var dest = parseInt($("#block").css("margin-left").replace("px", "")) + 100;
  if (dest < 700) {
    $("#block").animate({
      marginLeft: dest + "px"
    }, 700);
  } else {

    $("#block").animate({
      marginLeft: "10px"
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #block {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    width: 120px;
  }
  
  #go {
    position: fixed;
  }
  
  #gold {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
    width: 120px;
  }
</style>
<img id="block" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/26AHz1avXH7VGg6nm/giphy.gif" />

<div id="go">&raquo; Run</div>

<gold id="gold" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/26AHz1avXH7VGg6nm/giphy.gif" />
```

Link to the program (*click the run text to move the image*)

http://jsfiddle.net/svr1nmd3/4/

Comment: I made a slight improvement to your CSS.  http://jsfiddle.net/natelegakis/c90vL8zy/

Answer (score 0):

If you want use the css class like you set in your code, you must add this code at the end of else condition:

```
document.getElementById('block').classList.add("gold")
```

and replace in css `#gold` with `.gold`.

Else you want to change image when whe bunny return at the start point add this code in se else condition.

```
document.getElementById('block').src = "https://media.giphy.com/media/2yzGhPePXTXpJe9pMm/giphy.gif"
```

But you must have the gif of golden bunny.

```js
let counter = -1;

$("#go").click(function() {

    const maxMarginRight = 300; // just to reduse the width of block for fast try
  var dest = parseInt($("#block").css("margin-left").replace("px", "")) + 100;
  
  const colorIndex = ['gold', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black']
  
  if (dest < maxMarginRight) {
    $("#block").animate({
      marginLeft: dest + "px"
    }, maxMarginRight);
  } else {
  
    counter++;
  
    $("#block").animate({
      marginLeft: "10px"
    }, 100);
    
    if (colorIndex.length > counter) {
        const nextColor = colorIndex[counter];
      const prevColor = colorIndex[counter - 1];
      
      // Here I add the class gold at bunny
      if (nextColor) document.getElementById('block').classList.add(nextColor);     
      if (prevColor) document.getElementById('block').classList.remove(prevColor);
    }
   
    
  }
});
```

```css
#block {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  width: 120px;

}

#go {
  position: fixed;
}

/* #gold use the id of elemement to set the style, .gold is a class and you can add/remove it from element */
.gold {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
  width: 120px;
}

.red {
  -webkit-filter: invert(40%) grayscale(100%) brightness(40%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(-50deg) saturate(400%) contrast(2);
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(40%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(-50deg) saturate(600%) contrast(0.8);
}

.blue {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(30%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(-180deg) saturate(700%) contrast(0.8);
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(30%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(-180deg) saturate(700%) contrast(0.8);
}

.green {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(40%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(50deg) saturate(1000%) contrast(0.8);
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(40%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(50deg) saturate(1000%) contrast(0.8);
}

.black {
  -webkit-filter: invert(30%) grayscale(100%) brightness(70%) contrast(4);
  filter: invert(30%) grayscale(100%) brightness(70%) contrast(4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="block" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/26AHz1avXH7VGg6nm/giphy.gif" />
<div id="go">&raquo; Run</div>
```

Comment: thank you! how would I go about changing the bunny to gold, then pink, then other colors with a while loop? I want to change it more than once but I can't seem to get the while loop to work.

Comment: A easy way is insert a counter that incremet when you  enter in else condition and a legend of color in an array, when you enter in else you remove the last class and insert the new class.
Obviusly it's to add new classes in css file, I'm not pretty good in styles so I copied some filter classes from this page https://codepen.io/stilllife00/pen/avXpgJ.
I edited the upper code with che changes.